# Variables are assigned in if else block of JavaScript but showing undefine when called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, react-redux

So I was writing some code for react-redux and I encounter this anomalous behaviour in javascript.
Below is the code.

```
case CONSTANTS.ADD_CARD: {
      const { listId, card } = action.payload;

      if(typeof state[listId]==="undefined"){
        let newCard = [...state[listId], card] //defined variable based on condition
      }else{
        let newCard = [card] //defined variable for fail condition
      }
      const newState = {
        ...state
      }
      newState[listId] = newCard //error undefined variable showing hear 
    
      return newState;
    }
```

The above code is a part of `switch` statement.

Also, I tried declaring a variable above `if/else` block and then initiated it in the `if/else` block, but encountered the same error.

I solved the problem using the ternary operator, but still wondering the reason for the problem. Please let me know the reason behind this.

Thank you

Comment: `let` variables are "block scoped" - adding `let newCard;` before the if/else will fix the issue - plus of course removing the `let`

Comment: Declare `newState` in the same scope you want to use it later. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo". Cheers.

Comment: `let`/`const` are block-scoped, So you should declare it in the nearest common scope.

Comment: as a side note, if you use TypeScript instead of plain JavaScript, the compiler will clearly alert of that kind of errors, and won't compile.

Comment: sorry for dumb comment ... is `...state[listId]` the desired effect when `typeof state[listId]==="undefined"` returns `true`?

Answer (score 4):

The `let` creates a variable that is local to the current block. You can either use the `var` keyword or define `newCard`  in a wider block.

```
case CONSTANTS.ADD_CARD: {
  const { listId, card } = action.payload;

  let newCard;

  if(typeof state[listId]==="undefined"){
    newCard = [...state[listId], card] //defined variable based on condition
  }else{
    newCard = [card] //defined variable for fail condition
  }
  const newState = {
    ...state
  }
  newState[listId] = newCard //error undefined variable showing hear 

  return newState;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have defined ***newCard*** variable inside if/else block and it is available inside that only. In the outer environment, it is hidden and the value for the same would be undefined.

```
case CONSTANTS.ADD_CARD: {
  const { listId, card } = action.payload;

  let newCard;
  if(typeof state[listId]==="undefined"){
    newCard = [...state[listId], card] //defined variable based on condition
  }else{
    newCard = [card] //defined variable for fail condition
  }
  const newState = {
    ...state
  }
  newState[listId] = newCard //error undefined variable showing hear 

  return newState;
}
```

This code will work for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to initiate and declare the variable in separate lines, you can use, ternary operator

```
case CONSTANTS.ADD_CARD: {
  const { listId, card } = action.payload;

  let newCard = (typeof state[listId]==="undefined") ? [...state[listId], card] : [card]
  const newState = {
    ...state
  }
  newState[listId] = newCard //error undefined variable showing hear 

  return newState;
}
```

This method will helps when declaring const variables